# Facebook Single Sign On asks for credentials instead of permission

Tags: ios, single-sign-on, facebook-sdk-4.x

We have implemented Facebook login with Single Sign On in an iOS app. I have a user testing who is logged in with FB SSO in several apps. So I would expect this user to see the "Continue as [name]" -button, but instead he is asked to login with FB username and password. SSO is enabled in app settings. 
On my own iPod touch this is working as expected, so I can't reproduce the error. I may lack some knowledge about how FB SSO is working.

Why would FB ask for credentials in his case? Is it a bug or a feature?

iOS: 11
FB SDK: 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had a similar problem and it was solved by upgrading the SDK to v 4.27.1

Comment: We just upgraded to 4.28.0 and the problem is solved :-)